# How can I start react app with specific page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a router like;

```
  <React.Fragment>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/page1" component={Page1} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/page2" component={Page2} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/page3" component={Page3} />
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </React.Fragment>
```

But when I start my app, it doesn't open with Page1. It opens as a blank page. How can I provide this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Redirect` component from `/` to `/page1`:

```
<Switch>
  <Redirect from="/" to="/page1" />

  <Route exact path="/page1" component={Page1} />
  <PrivateRoute path="/page2" component={Page2} />
  <PrivateRoute path="/page3" component={Page3} />
  <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'root' Route on top (or anywhere)

```
  <React.Fragment>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Page1} >
        <Redirect to="/page1" />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/page1" component={Page1} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/page2" component={Page2} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/page3" component={Page3} />
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </React.Fragment>
```